# using regex to find a number in a string

Tags: python-3.x

`i_know_this = "11.22"`

I'm really noobish with regular expressions.  I'm looking for a version number that starts with `"11.22"` but is incomplete in a string. An example of this string would be:

"bla bla bla bla 73.12. bla bla bla 11.22.33.444 bla"

in this string I would want extract `11.22.33.444` and tie to variable:
`z = "11.22.33.444"`

another example:

`"bla bla bla bla 13.762. bla bla bla 11.22.01.4. bla"`

and in this instance I would want to find `11.22.01.4` (no extra dot) and link that to a variable: 
`z = "11.22.01.4"`

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
import re

R=re.compile(r'(11\.22\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
S=R.search(yourstring) # I tried .match(); but that didn't work
S.group()
```

Comment: You need to make that a raw string, and don't escape the parentheses. `R=re.compile(r'(11\.22\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

`z = re.search( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', s ).group(0)`

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "bla bla bla bla 73.12. bla bla bla 11.22.33.444 bla"
>>> z = re.search( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', s ).group(0)
>>> print(z)
11.22.33.444

>>> s = "bla bla bla bla 13.762. bla bla bla 11.22.01.4. bla"
>>> z = re.search( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', s ).group(0)
>>> print(z)
11.22.01.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) :

```
import re  
a = 'bla bla bla bla 13.762. bla bla bla 11.22.01.4. bla'
b = 'bla bla bla bla 73.12. bla bla bla 11.22.33.444 bla'

r = re.compile(r'(11\.22\.[\d\.]+\d)')

print(r.findall(a))
print(r.findall(b))
```